# Counting records meeting multiple and variable criteria in SQL like countifs

Tags: sql-server, count, sum, aggregate-functions

I want to count records matching certain criteria, whose criteria are derived from the particular values in the row which vary widely.

The below table is an excerpt from a 50K+ records table;

```
BatchNumber     |  Number  | LabId | StateId |  Week   | OccurrenceId
----------------+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------------
101347-1M-37    |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201610 |    
101347-1-1546L  |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201611 |    
101347-1M-41    |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201614 |    
101347-1M-1545  |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201618 |    
101347-1-37     |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201607 |    
101347-1-1541   |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201611 |    
101347-1M-37    |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201616 |    
101347-1-1546L  |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201617 |    
101347-1M-41    |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201620 |
```

I want to count the occurrence of a record much like you could with a `countifs` function in Excel.

The `sum()` or `count()` functions combined with a `case` statement won't do the trick I think since the criteria vary according to the values in the row.

What I have in the statement to get occurrenceId so far is this:

```
sum(case when v.number = v.number 
          and b.LabId = b.LabId
          and po.StateId = po.StateId
          and po.Week < po.Week
         then 1 
         else 0 
     end) as occurenceid
```

This statement results in 0 for each record.

But omitting the `and po.Week < po.Week` part returns this (which for the life of me I don't understand, but it seems to head somewhere);

```
BatchNumber     |  Number  | LabId | StateId |  Week   | OccurrenceId
----------------+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------------
101347-1M-37    |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201610 |    1
101347-1-1546L  |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201611 |    1
101347-1M-41    |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201614 |    1
101347-1M-1545  |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201618 |    1
101347-1-37     |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201607 |    5
101347-1-1541   |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201611 |    2
101347-1M-37    |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201616 |    4
101347-1-1546L  |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201617 |    1
101347-1M-41    |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201620 |    1
```

I can not simply write `v.number = 101347 and b.LabId = 1 and po.StateId = 100` since I need all of the records counted and many different numbers, LabIds, StateIds etc. apply.

Just for clarity, the result I need to achieve would look like this:

```
BatchNumber     |  Number  | LabId | StateId |  Week   | OccurrenceId
----------------+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------------
101347-1M-37    |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201610 |    1
101347-1-1546L  |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201611 |    2
101347-1M-41    |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201614 |    3
101347-1M-1545  |  101347  |    1  |    100  |  201618 |    4
101347-1-37     |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201607 |    1
101347-1-1541   |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201611 |    2
101347-1M-37    |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201616 |    3
101347-1-1546L  |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201617 |    4
101347-1M-41    |  101347  |    1  |    101  |  201620 |    5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Used a subquery with multiple inner join conditions.

```
select v.Number, b.LabId, po.StateId, po.Week, count( sub.Week ) as occurrenceid

from Batch b

inner join ProductionOrder po on po.BatchId = b.BatchId
inner join Variety v on b.VarietyId = v.VarietyId
inner join 
    (select v.Number, b.LabId, po.StateId, po.Week

    from Batch b

    inner join ProductionOrder po on po.BatchId = b.BatchId
    inner join Variety v on b.VarietyId = v.VarietyId

    ) sub on v.number = sub.Number and b.LabId = sub.LabId and po.StateId = sub.StateId and po.Week >= sub.Week

where v.Number = 101347 and po.StateId > 99

group by v.Number, b.LabId, po.StateId, po.Week
```

It may not be the most elegant solution so still eager to see better answers.